# how to prevent onclick event to trigger in select option

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a select that triggers an event when it is clicked. But I want to prevent it to trigger again when I click in the respective option.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you try using onchange. So if there is not change in what is selected. Nothing is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Just use onchange event. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/rafb0vyw/2/

```
$('#sel').on('change', function() {
    alert('change');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property, which will have a different value. Like this:

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var span = document.querySelector('span');

select.onclick = function(e) {
    // show e.target in snippet (you would remove this line in your code):
    span.textContent = 'You clicked on ' + e.target.tagName + '.' +
         ' Current selected value is ' + select.value;
    if(e.target.tagName !== 'SELECT') return; // ignore
    // The rest of your event handling comes here...
    // This will only be executed when you click the SELECT and not the OPTION.
};
```

```html
<select>
     <option value = 'A'>Option A</option>
     <option value = 'B'>Option B</option>
</select>
<span></span>
```

Make sure to have the event parameter (named *e* in the above example) defined in your event handler function.

Comment: Then I assume you have something different, because all browsers support this. Did you run the snippet. Do you see the messages next to the drop-down when you click?

Comment: To me it works like this: when I click in select to select somethint it shows "you click in SELECT", then when I select an option it shows "you click in OPTION". Without any A or B after OPTION tag.

Comment: That is how it is intended to be . The question was not about showing the selected value. But about avoiding the event handler to run when an option was clicked.

Comment: but at least it shouldn't show the first event that shows SELECT don't you think ? If you say that this is what you intended then I delete my comments and apologize.

Comment: Who says it should do that? I am just demonstrating that the proposed answer works. My aim is not to write a program that displays the chosen option. I am not even sure the OP wants to do that. Anyway, I have added the value in the output now.

Comment: Well the option value really was secondary, what I found really strange is that with the `if(e.target.tagName !== 'SELECT') return; `the fist  "you click in SELECT" still apears.

Comment: That is intended, otherwise the previous message would still be there. Like I put in the comments of the code, this is just for illustrating what event.target is. I have put ample comments to indicate which parts gets only executed when the select is clicked. It should be clear that the `if` is only effective at the place where it is positioned in the code.

Comment: Ok sorry.. removed the downvote. My mistake. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: No offence taken. ;-)